# Shuffling Array - Missing number c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm really stuggling with how to phrase this, but I'm creating a program in C# which basically shuffles outputs it, but to avoid duplications I remove it from the ArrayList.

Now it works but sometimes it overrides a current number that's been said and leaves a button blank.

I'll show my code below:

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[3];
        int questionNumber = 0;
        int qNumber = 0;
        int x = 1;


Random r = new Random();
            List<Button> listOfButtons = new List<Button>();
            listOfButtons.Add(buttons[0]);
            listOfButtons.Add(buttons[1]);
            listOfButtons.Add(buttons[2]);



            int rIndex;

            while (qNumber < 3)
            {
                rIndex = r.Next(0, listOfButtons.Count); //Choose a random object from list
                listOfButtons[rIndex].Text = qAnswer[questionNumber, x++]; // adds text to button
                listOfButtons.Remove(buttons[rIndex]); // removes button from index
                qNumber++;


            }



private void EasyLevel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttons[0] = a1; // a1 is button
            buttons[1] = a2;
            buttons[2] = a3;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this, but I suggest this simple approach:

1) Use a shuffler class to shuffle arrays. This one uses the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
public class Shuffler
{
    public Shuffler()
    {
        _rng = new Random();
    }

    public void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> array)
    {
        for (int n = array.Count; n > 1; )
        {
            int k = _rng.Next(n);
            --n;
            T temp = array[n];
            array[n] = array[k];
            array[k] = temp;
        }
    }

    private readonly Random _rng;
}
```

2) You have a collection of questions which you want to access in a random order. If the questions are in an array or list, you can shuffle them directly. If they are not (which I am assuming) then instead you can create a list of indices from 0..n-1 where n is the number of questions:

```
var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, qAnswer.Count()).ToArray();
```

3) Then you shuffle those indices:

```
var shuffler = new Shuffler();
shuffler.Shuffle(indices);
```

4) Finally, you can use those indices (which are now in a random order) to access the questions in a random order:

```
foreach (var index in indices)
    buttons[0].Text = qAnswer[questionNumber, index];
```

(I'm not sure from the code you posted whether that should be `qAnwser[questionNumber, index]` or `qAnswer[index, questionNumber]` or something else, so you may have to change that...)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort a list in a random order, use a comparer that implements `IComaprer<T>`
Here's a RandomComparer I've written some years ago that has proved itself useful time after time:

```
public class RandomComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private Random rnd;
    public RandomComparer() {
        rnd = new Random();
    }

    public RandomComparer(int Seed) {
        rnd = new Random(Seed);
    }
    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return rnd.Next(-1, 2);
    }
}
```

To use it simply write this: `listOfButtons.Sort(new RandomComparer<Button>());`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having problems because the `listOfButtons.Remove(buttons[rIndex])` doesn't check for object equality as you think it does.

Try using `listOfButtons.RemoveAt(rIndex)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach that loops through Buttons instead of texts:

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[] 
{
    button1,
    button2,
    button3
};

List<string> text = new List<string>() {"1", "2", "3"};

Random random = new Random();

foreach (var button in buttons)
{
    string str = text[random.Next(0, text.Count() - 1)];
    button.Text = str;
    text.Remove(str);
}
```